# Using Mustache or any templating engine for a single page HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, performance, templates, cordova, mustache

I program using PhoneGap and learned that cross-platform apps really produces slow applications compared to native apps. I learned from http://floatlearning.com/2011/05/how-well-does-phonegap-scale/ that javascript templating will significantly increase the speed of my mobile app.

I develop single page apps. Magazine apps in particular. Contains an overflow:hidden container for pages and page transition is held by left and right swipes (CSS3 Translates). I would just like to ask how I can implement javascript templating (Mustache) to solve my performance problems with my magazine app.

Thank you and God Bless!

Comment: 1. Write a JSON API for your app. 2. Use mustache to render HTML in the browser. 3. ??? 4. Profit!

Comment: I'm not sure if Mustache is the cure for your performance woes. It's just a templating engine that will render to HTML, you could possibly end up with the exact same problems if you generate the roughly the same HTML and use the same scripts your current pages have. You might want to start profiling your app to see if you can pinpoint where the performance problems may lie.

Comment: profiling? can you give me more details on that. ty for the comments peeps!

Comment: I think pretty much every current browser now has developer tools available. [IE9 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478), [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), Firefox has extensions like Firebug and YSlow, and you can use those to profile your pages. There are also more tools like [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/overview.html) to see what might be affecting your page performance. If your apps have any back end components (server side processing), that could also be a point of slowness.

Comment: not really. my magazines dont use any back-end data. What my magazine do have is a bunch of images and I want to find a solution to speed my app up. I mean, seriously, it is SLOW. The only information I found is this Client-side Templating which I dont really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of performance when adding HTML to a page with Mustache vs a few other alternatives http://jsperf.com/adasdadsaddddddddddd

From your last comment though, your biggest performance boost could come from image optimization. You could use any of the developer tools mentioned to see how many HTTP requests you're making for images, the size of them, and where your bottlenecks are.

Use tools like [Smush.it](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/) to compress your current images. Look to combine images to sprites where it makes sense. Explore [CSS Data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

After you've optimized your HTTP requests and images, then look to speed up rendering time of the DOM. You may find that you could use something like Mustache to dynamically render "magazine pages" on swipe so you only have to layout the initial view.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze your app on page spped service and see **Critical path** report to check whats going on behind your website.
you can also use console of chrome using `performance.timing` , it will show exact time loading statics of page.